# Getting ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING on server when Django APIView is used

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, wsgi, gunicorn

We are using

- Django
- rest_framework
- gunicorn
- Postgres
- nginx

Everything is working locally. But on server, when I hit request from Chrome then I got ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error and when I did curl then response was

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

Even when I restart gunicorn then I immediately get the response for 1st request but then it hangs somewhere and further requests do not work.
I am returning a blank array in response to test which is not working so response length is not the concern.

In Django, I am inheriting MyView class from APIView(from rest_framework.views import APIView). When I changed APIView to View(from django.views import View) everything started working fine on server. Not sure what is causing issue? Is it APIView library or gunicorn.
I tried gunicorn locally and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added

```
'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware'
```

in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py and it started working. 
This class adds the Content-Length header in the response.

Answer (score 1):

You should change permissions of /var/lib/nginx/ for the user than execute gunicorn. If you user is username, you fix this error with:

```
chown -R username:username /var/lib/nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case the issue was happening because the box on which my server was hosted was hitting 100% Disk Usage and thus nginx was failing while writing the access logs.Just adding this in case someone hits the same issue. And so it might mean that there is some other issue and you should debug from a more holistic view.